# On one line, two elements left-most, one right-most, contents vertically centered on the line, no fixed sizes

Tags: html, css, positioning

My apologies if similar questions already exist (I know they do), but I didn't really find what I was looking for and I'm getting crazy here. I want the solution to work on Chrome; compatibility with other browsers is optional.

Let me draw a picture of what I want, hoping my ASCII art won't get messed up. The line of `x`s represents the page width:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
,-----------.   ,---.                                      
| Contents  |   |   |                            ,--------.
|           |   | B |                            | some C |
| A         |   |   |                            `--------'
`-----------'   `---'
```

A and B should be as close of each other as possible, and A should touch the left of my window. C should touch the right of my window. Between B and C is an empty area that varies with respect to the three elements sizes. If C has a smaller height than A or B, I want it to be centered vertically on the line. I'd like to not to use javascript for layout.

I tried many things, among which:

- Tables won’t do it, because they distribute size evenly OR I need to fix dimensions, which I can’t (content is dynamic, although the sizes are in a fixed (probably definable) range)
- Floated divs won’t be able to center their contents vertically unless displayed as table-cells, but then I cannot float them anymore.

(This sort of thing would be trivial in any modern GUI toolkit. Why are the web standards lagging so far behind?)

Comment: Can you explain how the contents of the boxes is to be distributed if you don't specify at least one of the dimensions of each box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zEaK9/

HTML:

```
<div class="left main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contents"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="center main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contents"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contents"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    height:100px;
}
.main{
    display:table;
}
.left{
    background:blue;
    width:65px;
    float:left;
}
.center{
    background:green;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
.right{
    background:orange;
    width:65px;
    float:right;
}
.container{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.contents{
    margin:auto;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background:lightGrey;
}
```

Comment: I believe if .center is 500px tall, .right needs to be vertically centered. Your fiddle results in: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/yXjmx/1/

Comment: @BrentAnderson, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Seems nice thanxs, I'll just have to try it in my app to see whether it works as expected with my actual contents :)

Comment: @Walkerneo, the height of .left and .center can be variable.  .right needs to be vertically centered to the tallest of .left and .center if it is shorter than either.  per the original question, "If C has a smaller height than A or B, I want it to be centered vertically on the line. "

Comment: @BrentAnderson, Oops, missed that bit.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a table?

This seems to do what you ask:

http://jsfiddle.net/btuwY/

The widths of A, B, and C are fixed, but they can be any values.

Comment: What's wrong is that, in my browser (chrome) at least, A, B, and C take up too much horizontal space (I want them as small as possible), and I can't get the divs to be vertical-aligned (http://jsfiddle.net/btuwY/13/)

Comment: Indeed.  I didn't realize that Chrome doesn't like "*".  Although I should have guessed.  Tables tend to be cross-browser mine-fields.

Answer (score 0):

Put all three divs A, B, C in a container div, then specify div C's `vertical-align` as `middle`. The container grows to the maximum of all three sizes, and then C is placed where you want it. (Of course, you float A and B to the left, and C to the right).